# How to merge files after using split command from terminal?

Tags: terminal, utilities

I've split a large file with the split command from a Terminal and copied it from a USB-stick to my MacBook.

This results in couple of files named 'xaa', 'xab', 'xac'.

How do I merge them together again from within a Terminal?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
cat xaa > newfile
cat xab >> newfile
cat xac >> newfile
```

Basically using a single '>' operand send the output to a new file.  using a double '>>' operand makes it append the contents to the end of an existing file (and also out of interest create it if it does not already exist.

If all your files are definitely in a neat alphabetical order, then you could use:

```
cat x* > newfile
```

or

```
cat xaa xab xac > newfile
```

in case the filenames aren't in alphabetical order.

Comment: You can also do `cat xaa xab xac > newfile`

Comment: but of course, this sounds logical! :-) thanks!

Comment: It _is the mac way_ after all.

Comment: @bmike More like _the Unix way_, am I right?! :)

Comment: I split a file in Ubuntu 16, then concatenated it in OS X, to an NTFS drive using Paragon's driver, and the end result file was different. (I checked by running `sha256sum filename` on Ubuntu and `openssl sha -sha256 filename` on OS X.) When I concatenated it to an HTFS+ drive the concatenated file was correct.

Comment: When I do `cat xaa xab xac > newfile`, then `newfile` ends up just being the same contents as `xaa`.  On OSX Sierra.  What am I missing?