# Why my macintosh hd hard drive has less capacity than it should?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, bootcamp, partition

Please look at this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

Why here is only 160 instead of 250? What is wrong? How can I reset this?

I have tried to use Boot Camp Assistant to install windows on a partition with 80GB but there was some error, and macbook crashed. How can I solve this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at [this Q&A](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/254676/88313).  It will tell you about the Purgeable space and why you only have 59,17GB free space available to do the install.

Comment: It is not the case I care... Why `Macintosh HD` has 160 instead of 251? And how to reset this? It happened because sth went wrong with Boot Camp Assistant, and now that space (80GB) is frozen and not available for me anymore... how can I reset this?

Comment: I didn't get that from your question.  You might want to edit it so it clearly states what the problem is and what solution you're looking for.  That might help you get better answers.

Comment: @fsb I need there 251GB again. Sth went wrong and there is currently 160GB. What can I do more... except hard reset of macbook?

Comment: Anyway, will hard reset bring my available space of 256 GB back?

Comment: I think you'll need to find a utility that can resize disk partitions. This will be tricky if it is your boot volume.