# Disk utility free space doesn't match Apple > About this Mac > Storage

Tags: disk-utility, mojave, ssd, disk-space

There's a difference of almost 6.14GB regarding how much *free* space both methods report.

What's going on here?
How much free space I actually have?

(The mounted image is very small, non worries about that)

[image]

Comment: I do not see a 200GB difference between these 2 reports. The System Information Storage tab shows 334,9GB available, and Disk Utility also shows the same 334,9GB available, with 6,14 GB purgeable.

Comment: Oh wow! It seems it was too late for me!! :D
What's the purgeable one tho? How to remove it?

Comment: Check out this question https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254676/how-do-i-clear-the-purgeable-area-on-my-disk