# Big Sur - how to remove purgeable storage - Terminal (2021)

Tags: terminal, disk-utility, big-sur, storage

Posting this since I have not been able to find a solution that works for Big Sur. I have deleted all the files in Optimize Storage and Purgeable still remains a huge number (and seems to have increased).

Terminal solution is fine!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this commands to purge snapshots :

```
tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 9999999999999 4
```

Comment: This will completely wipe out all local snapshots which might not be what you really want.  If you don't want any local snapshots, just disable macOS Time Machine, then you won't make any.  If you do want snapshots/time machine, then the above command will erase them all and I wouldn't recommend it.

Instead, you can just purge the space you need?  `tmutil thinlocalsnapshots / 10GB`.  Also keep in mind that macOS _should_ remove purgable space as needed so you shouldn't need to stress about erasing it.  Unless you're actually having problems.